# How to use v-for from computed property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I've got a component where I iterate over a draggable JS component using v-for

```
<div v-for="(val, index) in rows" :key="index"><draggable></draggable/></div>
```

My rows computed property returns an array of arrays. Array is a property that i'm receiving from the parent using v-model.

```
  props: {
    array: {
      type: Array,
      required: false,
      default: null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    rows () {
      if (isTrue) {
        const arr = this.array.map((v) => v.slice())
        const temp = doSomething(arr)
        return temp
      } else if (isFalse) {
        const arr = this.array.filter(elm => elm.length)
        return arr
      }
      return this.array
    }
```

However i'm getting an error: 'Cannot read property 'Sortable1616400528253' of null' When I change rows for array I dont get an error but the results are wrong which means that something is going wrong with rows. Any suggestions?

Comment: have you try using log or devtool to see what rows look like when error occurs?

Comment: In your computed `rows`, `isTrue` and `isFalse` are both `undefined`. So `this.rows` will always be `this.array`. Another thing to note is that mutating component data inside `computed` properties is an anti-pattern in Vue. `computed` properties are different views on the same data. They are automatically updated when the data mutates, but they shouldn't mutate the data themselves.

Comment: isTrue and isFalse are both data properties, I didn't put them in the example code, my bad. I think the last part of the comment is the issue, rows will give a different output the moment I drag an element, and vue doesn't understand that part

Comment: you should reference it with this.isTrue and this.isFalse

Answer (score 0):

For the v-model, you need a property that satisfies the get and set operation.
Immutable transformation is required for component props.
For this reason, you can develop a solution like the example.

```js
var bicomponent=Vue.component('biComponent', {
    template: `<div> 
  <draggable v-model="rows">
    <transition-group>
        <div v-for="(item, index) in rows" :key="item.id">
            {{item.text}}
        </div>
    </transition-group>
</draggable></div>`,
  components:{vuedraggable},
  props: {
    todoList: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
      default: []
    }
  },
  data: function () {
        return {
            rows: this.todoList
        }
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/metalsimyaci/wqxkzu4g/49/)